# IndexedDB module breaks functionality

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I had decided to build a PWA for experience in JavaScript and decided to use IndexedDB to store data as the project houses stats for players that have been looked up.

I decided to make an [IndexedDB wrapper with promises for other projects](https://github.com/ericmatz/IndexedDB_Wrapper_Promises/blob/main/database.js) as I thought that would be useful. I built and tested it without proper module syntax and as just a collection of functions to test. When I added export to abide by proper module requirements, some things stopped working.

Besides obvious code refactoring that needs to be done, I can't see why it is not function when actually put into a module, at least why some functions don't work while others do still.

I have one record in my object store currently:

```
1:"{"stats":{"skill":{"Overall":{"Rank":420475,"Level":1703,"Experience":41536951},"Attack":{"Rank":365100,"Level":90,"Experience":5348211},"Defence":{"Rank":387640,"Level":86,"Experience":3643081},"Strength":{"Rank":681596,"Level":86,"Experience":3619845},"Hitpoints":{"Rank":568026,"Level":89,"Experience":5338699},"Ranged":{"Rank":615697,"Level":86,"Experience":3872192},"Prayer":{"Rank":543130,"Level":70,"Experience":765936},"Magic":{"Rank":858588,"Level":77,"Experience":1586816},"Cooking":{"Rank":533540,"Level":75,"Experience":1265604},"Woodcutting":{"Rank":128685,"Level":90,"Experience":5396564},"Fletching":{"Rank":534221,"Level":75,"Experience":1210429},"Fishing":{"Rank":325821,"Level":80,"Experience":2088438},"Firemaking":{"Rank":802393,"Level":65,"Experience":454386},"Crafting":{"Rank":526605,"Level":70,"Experience":771273},"Smithing":{"Rank":508338,"Level":70,"Experience":763913},"Mining":{"Rank":527787,"Level":70,"Experience":761613},"Herblore":{"Rank":400792,"Level":70,"Experience":750904},"Agility":{"Rank":715721,"Level":65,"Experience":466967},"Thieving":{"Rank":516257,"Level":61,"Experience":310438},"Slayer":{"Rank":597053,"Level":72,"Experience":989731},"Farming":{"Rank":396681,"Level":74,"Experience":1102421},"Runecrafting":{"Rank":238233,"Level":66,"Experience":526072},"Hunter":{"Rank":634376,"Level":61,"Experience":321529},"Construction":{"Rank":602088,"Level":55,"Experience":181889}},"boss":{"Abyssal Sire":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Alchemical Hydra":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Barrows Chests":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Bryophyta":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Callisto":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Cerberus":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Chambers of Xeric":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Chambers of Xeric: Challenge Mode":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Chaos Elemental":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Chaos Fanatic":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Commander Zilyana":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Corporeal Beast":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Crazy Archaeologist":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Dagannoth Prime":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Dagannoth Rex":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Dagannoth Supreme":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Deranged Archaeologist":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"General Graardor":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Giant Mole":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Grotesque Guardians":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Hespori":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Kalphite Queen":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"King Black Dragon":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Kraken":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Kree'Arra":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"K'ril Tsutsaroth":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Mimic":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Nightmare":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Obor":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Sarachnis":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Scorpia":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Skotizo":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"The Gauntlet":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"The Corrupted Gauntlet":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Theatre of Blood":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Thermonuclear Smoke Devil":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"TzKal-Zuk":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"TzTok-Jad":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Venenatis":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Vet'ion":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Vorkath":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Wintertodt":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Zalcano":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Zulrah":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0}},"activity":{"League Points":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Bounty Hunter - Hunter":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Bounty Hunter - Rogue":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Clue Scrolls (all)":{"Rank":1306445,"Participation":2},"Clue Scrolls (beginner)":{"Rank":798671,"Participation":1},"Clue Scrolls (easy)":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Clue Scrolls (medium)":{"Rank":961590,"Participation":1},"Clue Scrolls (hard)":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Clue Scrolls (elite)":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"Clue Scrolls (master)":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0},"LMS - Rank":{"Rank":0,"Participation":0}}},"username":"limerain","type":"Standard","timestamp":1606315205012,"id":1}"
```

Module -

```
/**
 * Opens a connection to an indexedDB database
 * @param {string} database_name Name of indexedDB to be opened
 * @param {number} database_version Version of database to be opened
 * @param {function} upgrade_function Function to be executed if database needs to be upgraded
 * @returns {Promise} Resolve => IDBDatabase | Reject => Error
 */
function openDB(database_name, database_version, upgrade_function) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let request = indexedDB.open(database_name, database_version);

        request.onsuccess = function () {
            console.log("Database opened successfully")
            resolve(request.result);
        }

        request.onerror = function (event) {
            reject(`Error: openDB - Request Failed - Supplied Data {${database_name},${database_version},${upgrade_function}} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${request.error}`)
        };

        request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
            console.log('OnUpgradeNeeded - Called')
            upgrade_function(event.target.result)
                .then(console.log("Database Upgrade Successful"))
                .catch((reason) => {
                    reject(`Error: openDB - Database Upgrade Failed - Reason: ${reason}, Supplied Data {${database_name},${database_version},${upgrade_function}} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${request.error}`)
                })
        };
    });
}

/**
 * Adds record objects to the specificed objectStore
 * @param {IDBDatabase} database Initiliazed database
 * @param {string} storeName Name of objectStore where transactions will be occurring
 * @param {[object]} data Object to be inserted into the objectStore
 * @returns {Promise} Resolve => String | Reject => Error
 */
function addRecords(database, storeName, data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let transaction = database.transaction(storeName, "readwrite");

        transaction.oncomplete = function () {
            console.log("Add Transaction Successful.");
            resolve("Add Transaction Succesful")
        };

        transaction.onabort = function (event) {
            reject(`Error: addRecord - Transaction Aborted - Supplied Data: {${database},${storeName},${data}} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${event.target.error}`)
        }

        transaction.onerror = function (event) {
            reject(`Error: addRecord - Transaction Failed - Supplied Data: {${database},${storeName},${data}} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${event.target.error}`)
        };

        let objectStore = transaction.objectStore(storeName);

        data.forEach(record => {
            let request = objectStore.add(record);

            request.onsuccess = function () {
                console.log("Add Request Succesful");
            };

            request.onerror = function (event) {
                reject(`Error: addRecord - Request Failed: Supplied Data: {${database_name},${database_version},${upgrade_function}} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${request.error} Record: ${record}`)
            };

        })

    });
}

/**
 * Deletes records on a given Index and key from the specified objectStore
 * @param {IDBDatabase} database Initialized database
 * @param {string} storeName Name of ObjectStore where transactions will be occurring
 * @param {string} indexName An Index from a provided ObjectStore
 * @param {any} key Key being looked for
 */
function deleteRecords(database, storeName, indexName, key) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let transaction = database.transaction(storeName, "readwrite");

        transaction.oncomplete = function () {
            console.log("Delete Transaction Successful.");
            resolve("Records Deletion Successful")
        };

        transaction.onabort = function (event) {
            reject(`Error: deleteRecords - Transaction Aborted - Supplied Data: {${database},${storeName},${indexName},${key} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${event.target.error}`)
        }

        transaction.onerror = function (event) {
            reject(`Error: deleteRecords - Transaction Failed - Supplied Data: {${database},${storeName},${indexName},${key} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${event.target.error}`)
        };

        let objectStoreCursor = transaction.objectStore(storeName).index(indexName).openCursor();

        objectStoreCursor.onsuccess = function (event) {
            let cursor = event.target.result;
            if (cursor) {
                if (cursor.value[indexName] === key) {
                    let request = cursor.delete();
                    request.onsuccess = function () {
                        console.log('Record Deleted:', cursor.value);
                    }
                    request.onerror = function (event) {
                        reject(`Error: deleteRecords - Request Failed - Cursor: ${cursor} Supplied Data: {${database},${storeName},${indexName},${key} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${event.target.error}`)
                    }
                }
                cursor.continue();
            }
            console.log("Delete Request(s) Successful")
        }

        objectStoreCursor.onerror = function (event) {
            resolve(`Error: deleteRecords - Cursor Failed - Supplied Data: {${database},${storeName},${indexName},${key} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${event.target.error}`)
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Returns all records from the provided ObjectStore searching on the provided Index
 * @param {IDBDatabase} database Initialized database
 * @param {string} storeName Name of ObjectStore where transactions will be occurring
 * @param {string} indexName An Index from a provided ObjectStore
 * @param {IDBKeyRange | any} key Key being looked for
 * @returns {Promise} Resolve => Array of Objects | Reject => Reason
 */
function getRecordsOnIndex(database, storeName, indexName, key) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let transaction = database.transaction(storeName, "readonly");

        transaction.oncomplete = function () {
            console.log("Get Transaction Successful.");
        };

        transaction.onabort = function (event) {
            reject(`Error: getRecordsOnIndex - Transaction Aborted - Supplied Data: {${database},${storeName},${indexName},${key}} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${event.target.error}`)
        }

        transaction.onerror = function (event) {
            reject(`Error: getRecordsOnIndex - Transaction Failed - Supplied Data: {${database},${storeName},${indexName},${key}} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${event.target.error}`)
        };

        let request = transaction.objectStore(storeName).index(indexName).getAll(key);

        request.onsuccess = function (event) {
            console.log("Get All Request Succesful");
            resolve(event.target.result)
        };

        request.onerror = function (event) {
            reject(`Error: getRecordsOnIndex - Request Failed - Supplied Data: {${database},${storeName},${indexName},${key}} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${event.target.error}`)
        };

    });
}

/**
 * Returns all records from the provided ObjectStore
 * @param database Initialized database
 * @param storeName  Name of ObjectStore where transactions will be occurring
 * @returns {Promise} Resolve => Array of Object | Reject => Reason
 */
function getRecordsOnObjectStore(database, storeName) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let transaction = database.transaction(storeName, "readonly");

        transaction.oncomplete = function () {
            console.log("Get All Transaction Successful.");
        };

        transaction.onabort = function (event) {
            reject(`Error: getRecordsOnObjectStore - Transaction Aborted - Supplied Data: {${database},${storeName}} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${event.target.error}`)
        }

        transaction.onerror = function (event) {
            reject(`Error: getRecordsOnObjectStore - Transaction Failed - Supplied Data: {${database},${storeName}} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${event.target.error}`)
        };

        let request = transaction.objectStore(storeName).getAll();

        request.onsuccess = function (event) {
            console.log("Get All Request Succesful");
            resolve(event.target.result)
        };

        request.onerror = function (event) {
            reject(`Error: getRecordsOnObjectStore - Request Failed - Supplied Data: {${database},${storeName}} Code: ${event.target.errorCode} Error: ${event.target.error}`)
        };

    })
}

export {
    openDB,
    addRecords,
    deleteRecords,
    getRecordsOnIndex,
    getRecordsOnObjectStore
}
```

My utilities module that houses shared data or functionality

```
function upgradeDB(database) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        //Create Table
        if (!database.objectStoreNames.contains('records')) {
            let records_table = database.createObjectStore('records', { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true })
            records_table.createIndex('username', 'username', { unique: false });
            records_table.createIndex('type', 'type', { unique: false });
            records_table.createIndex('id', 'id', { unique: true });
            resolve("Upgrade Successful.");
        } else {
            reject("ObjectStore already exists?")
        }
    });
}

function parseDate(UTC) {
  let date = new Date(UTC);
  return `${date.toLocaleDateString()} ${date.toLocaleTimeString()}`;
}

const HISCORE_PROFILE = [
    "Overall",
    "Attack",
    "Defence",
    "Strength",
    "Hitpoints",
    "Ranged",
    "Prayer",
    "Magic",
    "Cooking",
    "Woodcutting",
    "Fletching",
    "Fishing",
    "Firemaking",
    "Crafting",
    "Smithing",
    "Mining",
    "Herblore",
    "Agility",
    "Thieving",
    "Slayer",
    "Farming",
    "Runecrafting",
    "Hunter",
    "Construction",
    "League Points",
    "Bounty Hunter - Hunter",
    "Bounty Hunter - Rogue",
    "Clue Scrolls (all)",
    "Clue Scrolls (beginner)",
    "Clue Scrolls (easy)",
    "Clue Scrolls (medium)",
    "Clue Scrolls (hard)",
    "Clue Scrolls (elite)",
    "Clue Scrolls (master)",
    "LMS - Rank",
    "Abyssal Sire",
    "Alchemical Hydra",
    "Barrows Chests",
    "Bryophyta",
    "Callisto",
    "Cerberus",
    "Chambers of Xeric",
    "Chambers of Xeric: Challenge Mode",
    "Chaos Elemental",
    "Chaos Fanatic",
    "Commander Zilyana",
    "Corporeal Beast",
    "Crazy Archaeologist",
    "Dagannoth Prime",
    "Dagannoth Rex",
    "Dagannoth Supreme",
    "Deranged Archaeologist",
    "General Graardor",
    "Giant Mole",
    "Grotesque Guardians",
    "Hespori",
    "Kalphite Queen",
    "King Black Dragon",
    "Kraken",
    "Kree'Arra",
    "K'ril Tsutsaroth",
    "Mimic",
    "Nightmare",
    "Obor",
    "Sarachnis",
    "Scorpia",
    "Skotizo",
    "The Gauntlet",
    "The Corrupted Gauntlet",
    "Theatre of Blood",
    "Thermonuclear Smoke Devil",
    "TzKal-Zuk",
    "TzTok-Jad",
    "Venenatis",
    "Vet'ion",
    "Vorkath",
    "Wintertodt",
    "Zalcano",
    "Zulrah",
  ];
  
  const SKILLS = [
    "Overall",
    "Attack",
    "Defence",
    "Strength",
    "Hitpoints",
    "Ranged",
    "Prayer",
    "Magic",
    "Cooking",
    "Woodcutting",
    "Fletching",
    "Fishing",
    "Firemaking",
    "Crafting",
    "Smithing",
    "Mining",
    "Herblore",
    "Agility",
    "Thieving",
    "Slayer",
    "Farming",
    "Runecrafting",
    "Hunter",
    "Construction",
  ];
  
  const BOSS_KILLS = [
    "Abyssal Sire",
    "Alchemical Hydra",
    "Barrows Chests",
    "Bryophyta",
    "Callisto",
    "Cerberus",
    "Chambers of Xeric",
    "Chambers of Xeric: Challenge Mode",
    "Chaos Elemental",
    "Chaos Fanatic",
    "Commander Zilyana",
    "Corporeal Beast",
    "Crazy Archaeologist",
    "Dagannoth Prime",
    "Dagannoth Rex",
    "Dagannoth Supreme",
    "Deranged Archaeologist",
    "General Graardor",
    "Giant Mole",
    "Grotesque Guardians",
    "Hespori",
    "Kalphite Queen",
    "King Black Dragon",
    "Kraken",
    "Kree'Arra",
    "K'ril Tsutsaroth",
    "Mimic",
    "Nightmare",
    "Obor",
    "Sarachnis",
    "Scorpia",
    "Skotizo",
    "The Gauntlet",
    "The Corrupted Gauntlet",
    "Theatre of Blood",
    "Thermonuclear Smoke Devil",
    "TzKal-Zuk",
    "TzTok-Jad",
    "Venenatis",
    "Vet'ion",
    "Vorkath",
    "Wintertodt",
    "Zalcano",
    "Zulrah",
  ];
  
  const ACTIVITIES = [
    "League Points",
    "Bounty Hunter - Hunter",
    "Bounty Hunter - Rogue",
    "Clue Scrolls (all)",
    "Clue Scrolls (beginner)",
    "Clue Scrolls (easy)",
    "Clue Scrolls (medium)",
    "Clue Scrolls (hard)",
    "Clue Scrolls (elite)",
    "Clue Scrolls (master)",
    "LMS - Rank",
  ];
  
  const DATABASE_NAME = "runescape_tracker_pwa";

export {upgradeDB, parseDate, HISCORE_PROFILE, SKILLS, BOSS_KILLS, ACTIVITIES, DATABASE_NAME}
```

My module on the page to delete/view a record

```
import { openDB, deleteRecords, getRecordsOnObjectStore } from "./libraries/IndexedDB_Wrapper_Promises/database.js"
import { DATABASE_NAME, upgradeDB, parseDate } from "./utilities.js"

const OBJECTSTORE = "records";

function createRecordEntry(value) {

    let div = "";
    Object.entries(value).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        div += `
        <div class="recordEntry">
            <div class="button-group">
                <button data-id=${value.id} class="btnView">View</button>
                <button data-id=${value.id} class="btnDelete">Delete</button>
            </div>
            <div>${parseDate(parseInt(key))}</div>
        </div>
        `
    });

    return div;
}

function createTypeEntry(value) {

    let div = "";

    Object.entries(value).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        div += `
        <div class="typeEntry">
        <h3>${key}</h3>
        ${createRecordEntry(value)}
        </div>
    `
    })

    return div;
}

function createElement(username, value) {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "collection"
    div.innerHTML = `
            <h2>${username}</h2>
            ${createTypeEntry(value)}
`
    return div;
}

function buildResultSet(data) {

    let list = {};

    data.forEach(row => {
        if (list.hasOwnProperty(row.username)) {
            list[row.username][row.type] = { ...list[row.username][row.type], [row.timestamp]: { 'stats': row.stats, 'id': row.id } };
        } else {
            list = { ...list, [row.username]: { [row.type]: { [row.timestamp]: { 'stats': row.stats, 'id': row.id } } } };
        }
    });

    return list;
}

function deleteRecord(event) {
    openDB(DATABASE_NAME, 1, upgradeDB)
        .then(database => {
            console.log(database)
            deleteRecords(database, "records", "id",1)
                .then(result => { console.log(result) })
                .catch(result => { throw result });
        })
        .catch(result => { throw result })

}

function viewRecord(event) {
    window.location.assign(`view.html?id=${parseInt(event.target.dataset.id)}`)
}

window.onload = function () {
    openDB(DATABASE_NAME, 1, upgradeDB)
        .then((database) => {
            getRecordsOnObjectStore(database, OBJECTSTORE)
                .then((results) => {
                    let resultSet = buildResultSet(results)
                    Object.entries(resultSet).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(createElement(key, value));
                    });

                    let deleteButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("btnDelete");

                    Array.from(deleteButtons).forEach(button => {
                        button.addEventListener("click", deleteRecord)
                    });

                    let viewButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("btnView");

                    Array.from(viewButtons).forEach(button => {
                        button.addEventListener("click", viewRecord)
                    });

                })
                .catch((result) => {
                    throw result;
                });
        })
        .catch((result) => {
            throw result;
        });
};
```

1. DeleteRecords - should delete one record as it's on a unique index, however the cursor is returned as null

Calling function -

```
function deleteRecord(event) {
    openDB(DATABASE_NAME, 1, upgradeDB)
        .then(database => {
            deleteRecords(database, 'records', 'id', parseInt(event.target.dataset.id))
                .then(result => { console.log(result) })
                .catch(result => { throw result });
        })
        .catch(result => { throw result })
}
```

My module that builds a page for a specific record

```
import {openDB, getRecordsOnIndex} from "./libraries/IndexedDB_Wrapper_Promises/database.js"
import {DATABASE_NAME,upgradeDB,parseDate} from "./utilities.js"

window.onload = function () {
    let skillsTable = document.getElementById("skillTable"), otherTable = document.getElementById("otherTable"), usernameHeader = document.getElementById("usernameHeader"), recordTimestamp = document.getElementById("recordTimestamp"), recordID = document.getElementById("recordID");

    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
    console.log(params.get('id'))

    openDB(DATABASE_NAME, 1, upgradeDB)
        .then((database) => {
            getRecordsOnIndex(database, 'records', 'id', parseInt(params.get('id')))
                .then((results) => {
                    console.log(results)
                    if(results.length == 1){
                        usernameHeader.innerHTML = results[0].username
                        recordTimestamp.innerHTML = `Date: ${parseDate(results[0].timestamp)}`
                        recordID.innerHTML = `ID: ${results[0].id}`
                        buildTable(results[0].stats)
                    }else{
                        console.error("No results returned for the provided ID")
                    }
                })
                .catch((result) => {
                    throw result;
                });
        })
        .catch((result) => {
            throw result;
        });

    function buildTable(data) {
        //skill,boss,game
        Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, values]) => {
            //skill/activity
            Object.entries(values).forEach(([entry, values2]) => {
                //determine which table it falls under
                Object.keys(values2).length == 3
                    ? (newRow = skillsTable.insertRow(-1))
                    : Object.keys(values2).length == 2
                        ? (newRow = otherTable.insertRow(-1))
                        : _throw(
                            `Error: Unknown Data Structure In buildTable: \n Key: ${key} \n Value: ${values2}`
                        );
                newRow.className = entry;
                newRow.insertCell(-1).outerHTML = `<th scope="row">${entry}</th>`;

                //newRow.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry));
                //rank:x,level/participation/experience
                Object.entries(values2).forEach(([col, value]) => {
                    newRow.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
                });
            });
        });
    }
};
```

2. getRecordsOnIndex - returns an empty array instead of an array with a singular object in the current usage (index is primary keys)

Calling function -

```
openDB(DATABASE_NAME, 1, upgradeDB)
        .then((database) => {
            getRecordsOnIndex(database, 'records', 'id', parseInt(params.get('id')))
                .then((results) => {
                    console.log(results)
                    if(results.length == 1){
                        usernameHeader.innerHTML = results[0].username
                        recordTimestamp.innerHTML = `Date: ${parseDate(results[0].timestamp)}`
                        recordID.innerHTML = `ID: ${results[0].id}`
                        buildTable(results[0].stats)
                    }else{
                        console.error("No results returned for the provided ID")
                    }
                })
                .catch((result) => {
                    throw result;
                });
        })
        .catch((result) => {
            throw result;
        });
```

Comment: Where is the module syntax? How does it differ from the working code? And what exactly doesn't work, what errors do you get?

Comment: Sorry, the [hyper-link was to the full module on github](https://github.com/ericmatz/IndexedDB_Wrapper_Promises/blob/main/database.js)

The difference in functionality -

Delete - Nothing is deleted, the cursor is null when it shouldn't be
getRecordsOnIndex - returns an empty array instead of an array with a singular object in the current usage (index is primary keys)

There are no errors in the code, some of the functionality is just broken when I add the export.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all the relevant code itself, not just a link to it.

Comment: All modules are now on the post, was trying to remove as much fluff as I could, sorry!

Comment: I guess one module would have sufficed. But again, how does the working code differ? Are you saying that once you remove the `export { … }` declaration from each module, it magically starts working? How did you export and import the functions before you switched to ES6?

Comment: Yes, removing the export/import declarations from each module it magically starts working. Previously, it was just a collection of functions and I had the file placed above the calling file.

Comment: Removing export/import means global scope, are these files not being loaded as modules? Is this running in an HTML page? What does the script tag look like?

Comment: <script type="module" src="src/scripts/records.js"></script>

It seems the problem lays with the keypath (id) and defining an index for it as well. Using the getRecordOnIndex with an actual set index (username or type) returns the proper results.

Am I not allowed to write an index for the auto-increment keypath?